# Refresh a stale symlink linux

Tags: linux, bash, release

Is there a way to refresh a symlink once it has changed or gone stale?

I have a script which points to a link say:

```
/apps/myapps/release/current/....
```

Where current is a symlink pointing to say the latest release

Later I try to use a this link in a manner like

```
apps/myapps/release/current/scripts/start.sh
```

But if I have this `current` as working directory, changing the link won't change anything.

In order for this change to become effective, I would have to cd to apps/myapps/release and then back to `scripts` in order to access `start.sh`.

I am sure there must be a better way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe

```
cd `pwd`
```

would be perfect. Let me have a look:

```
cd /tmp
mkdir a
mkdir b
touch a/OLD
touch b/NEW
ln -snf a cur
cd cur
ls # shows OLD
ln -snf b /tmp/cur
ls # shows OLD
cd `pwd`
ls # shows NEW
```

Answer (score 3):

The wording in your question is a little vague, but from the title of your question, my answer is :

```
ln -f -s /apps/myapps/new/link/target mylink
```

Comment: So when I change the link I do rm to remove the link and then ln -s to create the new one. I can't see that this will be any different. Perhaps I wasn't to clear in that the link is stale.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd `pwd`
```

won't work in the case when you're in the symlink your script is updating. what i did to address this issue was:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="cd \`pwd\`"
```